# Trying to insert a line of php into template

Tags: php

I have installed a plugin and the user-interface tells me to insert the following code wherever I want it to appear.

```
<?php fb_page_plugin(); ?>
```

This is what I did:
1. I downloaded all of my website files using FileZilla.
2. I edited the footer.php file and inserted the line of code
3. Saved, uploaded the footer.php file, and refreshed my page.

But it doesn't show up?

```
</div>
    <?php if (function_exists("popular_ads")) { ?>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <h4><?php _e('Popular listing', 'boxer'); ?></h4>
    <?php popular_ads(30); ?>
    <div class="links popular">
        <ul>
        <?php if( osc_count_custom_items() == 0) { ?>
            <li><?php _e('No Popular Listings', 'boxer'); ?></li>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <?php while ( osc_has_custom_items() ) { ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo osc_item_url();?>">
                <?php echo osc_item_field('s_title'); ?></a>
                <?php fb_page_plugin(); ?>
                </li>
            <?php } ?>
         <?php } ?> 
     </ul>
```

Comment: The line of code is: <?php fb_page_plugin(); ?>

Comment: Have you tried adding an `echo` -> `<?php echo fb_page_plugin(); ?>`?

Comment: in conjunction with the above ^ - probably the extra `<?php` in this line `<li><a href="<?php echo osc_item_url(); ?>"><?php` that should be erroring out. Edit: I'm wrong. I didn't see the rest of the code on the right. Please use proper indentation.

Comment: Looks like there's a closing PHP tag (`?>`) missing in the line above the one you added.

Comment: Either you echo the function as @Sean said, or return/echo whatever you have in that function. You have your answer now.

Comment: your code is invalid as many other says because of the missing closing ?> tag where you echo osc_item_field('s_title')

Comment: I'm really trying to follow here, but I don't see the    ?>   to be missing?

Comment: I changed the line to           <?php echo fb_page_plugin(); ?>        but that didnt work either     =-/

Answer (score 0):

You probably inserted it not in the right place.

Unless you want it to print as many times as there are elements in `osc_has_custom_items()` you should move it out of `while` loop.

```
[...]
<ul>
    <?php if( osc_count_custom_items() == 0) { ?>
        <li><?php _e('No Popular Listings', 'boxer'); ?></li>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <?php while ( osc_has_custom_items() ) { ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo osc_item_url();?>">
            <?php echo osc_item_field('s_title'); ?></a>
            </li>
        <?php } ?>
     <?php } ?> 
 </ul>
 <?php fb_page_plugin(); ?>
```

So it will display (or not) regardless of `osc_count_custom_items()` size.